# Add generics to form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, generics

When I add a generic type to a form in C# I get errors like

> InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context

and the same for all of my components.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1<T> : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: Why would you want to add a generic type to your forms?

Comment: I wonder Where do you want to use that T

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, `Form1` is a *partial class*, it exists in more than one file.

Since you changed the `Form1.cs` file to have a generic `Form1<T>`, you also need to change the corresponding `Form1.Designer.cs` file to have a generic class.

Otherwise the C# compiler looks upon the two files as containing two distinct classes, one `Form1<T>` and one `Form1`. While they technically have the same name, they're distinct. You can declare a generic and a non-generic type with the same name at the same time.

So change both files.

---

Now, having said that, you cannot have generic forms. When you succeed in getting the compiler to compile the code (with the above described change) you will find that the form designer in Visual Studio is no longer happy with you and is unable to visually design the form.

As mentioned in the comments to this answer, if you can live without the form designer then this won't be a showstopper.

However, if you cannot live without the visual form designer then this cannot be fixed, other than to remove the generic parameters to `Form1` that you added in the first place.

So you should try to find a different way to do what you want.

Comment: I suppose if the OP is happy not to use the Visual Studio designer there isn't really an issue in having a generic form. I wouldn't suggest trying to handle the form's gui without the designer however

Answer (score 0):

`InitializeComponent()` is a method that Visual studio generates automatically for the forms created using visual designer. This method is located in `your_form_name.Designer.cs` class that is "visual" part of your form where controls placed on form defined.

Probably you've just copy-pasted it from another form created in such a way. If your custom class doesn't has "visual" part like `Form1.Designer.cs` class in your solution - then just delete this method call from constructor. Otherwise make sure your "visual" class part has this method.

Comment: Yes my class does have a visual component, I just want to pass a generic argument to an auto generated windows form.